# Reading nested structure using reflection

Tags: go, struct, reflection, slice, go-reflect

I write a recursive function that iterate over deep nested struct like the following:

```
type Container struct {
    Name string
    Items []Item
}

type Item struct {
    Name string
    Info Info
    Vals []string
}
// recursively reads nested struct, prints string values
func ReadStruct(st interface{}) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(st).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Type.Kind())
        switch val.Type().Field(i).Type.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            ReadStruct(val.Field(i)) // panic: call of reflect.Value.Elem on struct Value
        case reflect.Slice:
            // How to iterate over the reflect.Slice? 
        case reflect.String:
            fmt.Printf("%v=%v", val.Type().Field(i).Name, val.Field(i))
        }
    }
```

how to get access to inner objects (slices, structs) to work with them using reflect?
to iterate over slice i tried to use:

```
for i:= 0; i < val.Field(i).Slice(0, val.Field(i).Len()); i++ { //error: reflect.Value doesnt support indexing
//some work
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of errors in your code.

First, you only have to call [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) if the passed value is a pointer. When you iterate over the fields and you find a field of struct type, and you recursively call `ReadStruct()` with that, that won't be a pointer and thus you mustn't call `Elem()` on that.

So do it like this:

```
val := reflect.ValueOf(st)
if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    val = val.Elem()
}
```

Next, since you start `ReadStruct()` by calling [`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf), that assumes you have to pass non-reflect values to `ReadStruct()` (that is, not values of type [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value)).

But when you iterate over the fields, calling [`Value.Field()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Field), you get a `reflect.Value` wrapping the field. You have to call [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) to extract the non-reflect value form it, to be passed in recursive calls.

To iterate over slices, simply use [`Value.Len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Len) to get the slice length, and [`Value.Index()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Index) to get the i<sup>th</sup> element of the slice.

Here's the corrected version of your traversal function:

```
// I used this type as you didn't post it in your question.
type Info struct {
    Key, Value string
}

func ReadStruct(st interface{}) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(st)
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        val = val.Elem()
    }
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        // fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Type.Kind())
        f := val.Field(i)
        switch f.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            ReadStruct(f.Interface())
        case reflect.Slice:
            for j := 0; j < f.Len(); j++ {
                ReadStruct(f.Index(i).Interface())
            }
        case reflect.String:
            fmt.Printf("%v=%v\n", val.Type().Field(i).Name, val.Field(i).Interface())
        }
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
c := &Container{
    Name: "c1",
    Items: []Item{
        {
            Name: "i1",
            Info: Info{Key: "k1", Value: "v1"},
        },
        {
            Name: "i2",
            Info: Info{Key: "k2", Value: "v2"},
        },
    },
}
ReadStruct(c)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e6e9OWQJEw7)):

```
Name=c1
Name=i2
Key=k2
Value=v2
Name=i2
Key=k2
Value=v2
```

**Note:** By using recursive calls, you are extracting and re-acquiring `reflect.Value` values. It would be more efficient to always work with `reflect.Value`s, so you can avoid these unnecessary calls.

This is how you could do that:

```
func ReadStruct(st interface{}) {
    readStruct(reflect.ValueOf(st))
}

func readStruct(val reflect.Value) {
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        val = val.Elem()
    }
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        // fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Type.Kind())
        f := val.Field(i)
        switch f.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            readStruct(f)
        case reflect.Slice:
            for j := 0; j < f.Len(); j++ {
                readStruct(f.Index(i))
            }
        case reflect.String:
            fmt.Printf("%v=%v\n", val.Type().Field(i).Name, val.Field(i))
        }
    }
}
```

This will output the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OLdDQv4V4fk).